# How do I get pathogen working on Windows?

Tags: windows, git, vim, pathogen

Over the weekend I reengineered my .vim directory on OS X to use pathogen.vim. This worked perfectly and I checked everything into github once I finished.

Today, I pulled everything down to my Windows installation of vim and found out it doesn't work here.

The issue I'm encountering is that pathogen.vim doesn't load any plugins, and further, prevents loading anything else from my vimfiles directory (e.g., colorschemes). I've tried to debug it a little bit using `vim -V`. From what I can tell, pathogen.vim has a function called `pathogen#glob_directories` which is returning `[]` when it should be returning a list of all plugin directories. But I'm not really sure *why* this is happening.

Can someone help me figure out how to get pathogen working on Windows?

[My .vim files on github](https://github.com/krispharper/.vim) and in particular, [my .vimrc.](https://github.com/krispharper/.vim/blob/master/.vimrc)

Here is the output of `vim -V` with various error reporing levels.

[`vim -Vlog`](http://pastebin.com/qgPqp2pn)

[`vim -V12log`](http://pastebin.com/mPLb3dGR)

[`vim -V15log`](http://pastebin.com/uBtp97XT)

Comment: Pathogen has an [issue tracker](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/issues), try there instead.

Comment: I'm not sure how it is related to your issue but your `.vimrc` file should be called `vimrc` and you should delete `$HOME/_vimrc` (that presumably sources `$HOME/vimfiles/vimrc`) because 7.4 doesn't care if you have `$HOME/_vimrc` or `$HOME/vimfiles/_vimrc`.

Comment: I can post at the issue tracker. I just wasn't sure if it was a legitimate issue or something obvious I was missing.

To your second comment, perhaps I am missing something. When I remove `$HOME/.vimrc` (which sources `$HOME/vimfiles/.vimrc`) and rename `$HOME/vimfiles/.vimrc` to `$HOME/vimfiles/_vimrc`, vim doesn't load it. All variants of `$HOME/vimfiles/[_|.]vimrc` do not seem to work without a `$HOME/.vimrc` file sourcing it.

Comment: That's `$HOME/vimfiles/vimrc`, without a `.` or `_`, sorry. It's one of the two default locations on Windows; the other one being `$HOME/_vimrc`. `$HOME/.vimrc` is for UNIX-y systems: it has nothing to do on a windows machine.

Comment: @romainl Ah, I see now. It is working with just a vimrc in vimfiles. Hopefully this will work on OS X and Ubuntu as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know what the issue is. It seems that pathogen doesn't handle UNC paths correctly. They start with two slashes and pathogen is changing many of them into a single slash.

Comment: Note that that single vimrc trick is new in 7.4 so if you still have 7.3 on one of your machines you'll still need a ~/.vimrc. If it's of any help, you should use runtime vimrc in that file. And you should submit an issue to tim pope.